# Alternatives for allowing database connection from browser-based web form

Tags: 2007, forms-services

I know that it's impossible to connect directly from a browser-based infopath form to a database unless it's made through a web service.

I wonder what alternatives or workarounds are in order to simplify that connection. May I bring up the information from a BDC connection into a few lists and after that create data connecions to those lists from my infopath form? all ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

im taking a shot in the dark here:

considering you can have an InfoPath Form Web Part, cant you create a custom propertie that is set in the base class (get/set). It can contain the DB values and connection strings to connect to the DB?

If its done in a normal webpart on a sharepoint site why wouldnt it be possible to do it on an infopath webpart? That way it would contain either default values that can be changed and/or nothing (needs to be set). within the webpart you can have a nice interface that adds the values to the webpart properties for the DB connection if you want to give that kind of settings or have it so that its only accessible in the properties when you edit the webpart (limmited access)